# Get all keys with values for a specific date in an array of dictionaries SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of dictionaries:

```
var eventDetailsArray = [[String: String]]()
var events: [String: String] =  ["name":"block A”,  "date":"Friday, 23 Nov 2018"]
var events1: [String: String] = ["name":"block AB”, "date":"Friday, 23 Nov 2018"]
var events2: [String: String] = ["name":"block B",  "date":"Tuesday, 13 Nov 2018"]
var events3: [String: String] = ["name":"block C",  "date":"Wednesday, 28 Nov 2018"]

eventDetailsArray.append(events)
eventDetailsArray.append(events1)
eventDetailsArray.append(events2)
eventDetailsArray.append(events3)

var eventNamesArray = [String]()
```

I want an output array with event names for date selected only.
E.g; if ”Friday, 23 Nov 2018" is selected; I should get "block A” and "block AB” in the output array in SWIFT

Comment: You can use `filter()` for that. Did you try anything?

Comment: I am new to programming, However I tried for loop for that:
for i in eventDetailsArray{
}
but nothing fruitful

Comment: And what was your attempt? There is nothing wrong in doing a for loop, if you are new to programming. That's basic logic that might help you in the future instead of using a high level method like `filter()` (which is valid too).

Comment: The given example doesn't compile. Please formulate a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are encouraged to use a custom struct or class and `Date` instances for the dates. One reason is that this string representation of a date is not sortable

Comment: sure, thanks for the advice @vadian

Comment: @Larme , the attempt was to get these event name that I can forward to other view controller for specific date. Thanks to you guys; it is solved :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like so:

```
let str = "Friday, 23 Nov 2018"
eventNamesArray = eventDetailsArray.compactMap { $0["date"] == str ? $0["name"] : nil }
```

And the result is:

```
print(eventNamesArray)  //["block A", "block AB"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `filter` method:

```
var eventNamesArray = eventDetailsArray.filter { $0["date"] == "Friday, 23 Nov 2018" }
```

Maybe you should also consider using `Date` instead of Strings to represent the date. Especially, if you are interested in supporting different languages / locales.